# How to get X & Y resolution in DPI for the android platform?

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap, resolution

How do I obtain the X & Y resolution of a Bitmap in DPI on the android platform?
I'm expecting some api like 'GetXResInDPI()' like below :

`double getXResolution(Bitmap bmp) {
    double lXRes = Bmp.GetXResInDPI();
    return lXRes;
}`

I'm unable to obtain any such method for the android platform in spite of scourging through the java doc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but it looks like you might be looking for getScaledHeight() / getScaledWidth().

```
int xdpi, ydpi;
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResources(getResources(), R.drawable.my_bitmap);
xdpi = bmp.getScaledWidth(metrics);
ydpi = bmp.getScaledHeight(metrics);
```

Again, I may be misunderstanding your question, but that sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: Hey thanks for this...!! However, getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics); doesn't work, as it depends on the current activity. I would like something that returns the x & y resolutions for a Bitmap that's passed to the function.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use Bitmap.getWidth() and Bitmap.getHeight()?

Comment: Bitmap.getWidth() and Bitmap.getHeight() would work...but only for small images. Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_absoluteImagePath); would fail for large images. However, to obtain only width & height, use as follows :       Options optionsBmpInfo = new Options();
      optionsBmpInfo.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
      Bitmap bitmapInfo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_absoluteImagePath,
        optionsBmpInfo);